# Problemas para crear una gráfica de pie IE7 (chartist.js)

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo un problema.

Quiero genera un gráfica de pie en IE7. Estoy usando chartist.js ya que es de código abierto y es para mi trabajo. solo q no me fije y lo estbaa corriendo en IE11 y todo bonito. Pero nesecito q corra en IE7 y pues no funciona. Alguna idea o otra librería q recomienden.

Gracias

Comment: IE7 en serio?  Necesitas actualizarte.

Comment: Es cuestión del sistema del trabajo, así esta diseñado. Pero gracias por el aporte, ayudo mucho.

Comment: Debes agregar lo que has trabajado hasta ahora, para poder replicar tu problema.